# Extract an array from a Json file to put it in a class object

Tags: java, json, gson

so these are my classes

```
public class Fencers{
    private String name,nation;
    private int id;

    public Fencers(String name, String nation,int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nation = nation;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

the following class stores the other class objects in an Array List

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class FencersList {
    private ArrayList<Fencers> collection;
    public FencersList(){
        collection = new ArrayList<Fencers>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Fencers> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }

    public void addfencer(Fencers fencer){
        collection.add(fencer);
    }
    public String toString(){ //the toString method
        System.out.println("**************** FENCERS ****************");
        String total = "\n";
        for (int i = 0;i<collection.size();i++){
            Fencers b = (Fencers) collection.get(i);
            total = total + b.toString();
        }
        return total;
    }
    public void printFencers(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

and finally here is the main

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.*;


class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fencers fencer1 = new Fencers("m","egy",100);
        Fencers fencer2 = new Fencers("342","egy",120);
        FencersList list = new FencersList();
        list.addfencer(fencer1);
        list.addfencer(fencer2);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file.json"))) {
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(list.getCollection());
            out.write(jsonString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.json"));
            Fencers[] fencers = gson.fromJson(br,Fencers[].class);
            System.out.println(fencers);
            list.addfencer(fencers);
        } catch (Exception f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

here I managed to save `FencersList` class object in a the `file.json` everything works fine
my only problem here is I can't convert the data back to `FencersList` simply because this format makes it so that `Fencers` is an array and `FencerList` only accepts normal class objects from `Fencers` and when I fix it and make it normal it gives me an error `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` so I am a little bit stuck.

this is the `file.json` btw

```
[
  {
    "name":"m",
    "nation":"egy",
    "id":100}
 ,{
   "name":"342",
   "nation":"egy",
   "id":120
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error here is that when you saving collection to json file, but trying to read collection as FencersList object.

I am talking about this line:

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(list.getCollection());
```

This means that if you want to convert this jsonString back target object type should be the same as result of *list.getCollection()*, i.e. List. But instead of this you are trying deserialize json string to Fencers[]. It will not work

In order to be able to deserialize to *FencersList* you should create your json with

```java
String jsonString = gson.toJson(list);
```

Which will make your json looks like this (collection is the name of field in your *FencersList* class):

```json
{ "collection":[{"name":"m", "nation":"egy", "id":100}] }
```

Comment: okay I have done that and it works but how can I turn it back with to ```FencerList```'s collection

Comment: I have done that to read the file ```FencersList fencersList = gson.fromJson(reader, FencersList.class);``` but I cannot increment it to the class as an object

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot increment it to the class as an object"?

Comment: I just want it that when I run list.print(); it prints the data inside the json file. (just edited the ```FencersList``` class

Comment: this shoulf be the output **************** FENCERS ****************
103 m egy
120 342 egy

Comment: list.print()? Interface List doesn't have print method. Maybe you meant FencersList. In this case I suggest you to use iniside fencersList toString method 
String.join(",", collection). It will make you nice string of fencers separated by comma. Just don't forget to add toString to your Fencers class